# Another guvcview issue? Core dump!

Tags: guvcview

guvcview is core dumping with my Sony Handycam plugged in.  It works fine with my standard Logitech Webcam.   I deleted the config file so it could re-create it.

here is the output:

```
$ guvcview
guvcview 1.5.3
Could not open /home/rayj/.guvcviewrc for read,
 will try to create it
write /home/rayj/.guvcviewrc OK
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES failed : Input/output error(5)
ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES failed : Input/output error(5)
ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES failed : Input/output error(5)
ALSA lib audio/pcm_bluetooth.c:1614:(audioservice_expect) BT_GET_CAPABILITIES failed : Input/output error(5)
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server socket
jack server is not running or cannot be started
video device: /dev/video0 
ERROR opening V4L2 interface for /dev/video1
Init. stk1160 (location: usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.5)
{ pixelformat = 'UYVY', description = '16 bpp YUY2, 4:2:2, packed' }
VIDIOC_ENUM_FRAMESIZES - Error enumerating frame sizes: Inappropriate ioctl for device
  Unable to enumerate frame sizes.
: Inappropriate ioctl for device
{ pixelformat = 'RGB3', description = 'RGB3' }
{ ?GSPCA? : width = 720, height = 480 }
fmtind:2 fsizeind: 1
{ pixelformat = 'BGR3', description = 'BGR3' }
{ ?GSPCA? : width = 720, height = 480 }
fmtind:3 fsizeind: 1
{ pixelformat = 'YU12', description = 'YU12' }
{ ?GSPCA? : width = 720, height = 480 }
fmtind:4 fsizeind: 1
{ pixelformat = 'YV12', description = 'YV12' }
{ ?GSPCA? : width = 720, height = 480 }
fmtind:5 fsizeind: 1
vid:05e1 
pid:0408 
driver:stk1160
checking format: 1196444237
Format unavailable: 1196444237.
Init v4L2 failed !! 
Init video returned -2
trying minimum setup ...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```